# Concatenate two variables

Tags: php, variables

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
$errmsg_1 = 'Please make changes to your post';
$errmsg_2 = 'Please make changes to your post image';

$error = 1;

echo $errmsg_.$error; //'Please make changes to your post';
```

Nothing will work, and there are many error messages like these ones that I have to echo.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why not just throw all of the error messages in an array and echo $errormsg[$error]?

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. In the end, we decided to use the array solution suggested by many here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Store error messages in array:

```
$errmsg[1] = 'Please make changes to your post';
$errmsg[2] = 'Please make changes to your post image';

// and so on

$error = 1;

echo $errmsg[$error];
```

Answer (score 11):

What you're asking for is known as a *variable variable* -- see http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php for more info.

But please don't do that; it's considered very poor coding practice.

What you actually need is an array:

```
$errmsg = array(
    'Please make changes to your post',       //this will be $errmsg[0]
    'Please make changes to your post image'  //this will be $errmsg[1]
);

$error = 0;   //nb: arrays start at item number 0, not 1.

echo $errmsg[$error];
```

That's much better coding practice than messing around with variable variables.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
echo {'$errmsg_' . $error};
```

Although you're doing this really rather incorrectly. You should be using an array instead; concatenating variable names is bad practice and leads to messy/unreadable/broken code. Using an array would work like this:

```
$errors = array(
    'Please make changes to your post',
    'Please make changes to your post image'
);

echo $errors[$error];
```

Although bear in mind that `$error` starts from 0 as arrays are 0-index based.

Comment: `echo $errmsg_{$error};` it not valid, this would result `undefined variable $etc.`, correct use is `echo ${'errmsg_'.$error};`

Comment: @dbf Thank you - I was working from memory which rarely serves me well.

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head I think you want `$errmsg_{$error}`, but I'm not in a position to test/double check that right now.

Comment: `Undefined variable: errmsg_`

Comment: I actually agree with all of the folks saying an array is a better option in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$errmsg_1 = 'Please make changes to your post';
$errmsg_2 = 'Please make changes to your post image';

$error = 1;

echo ${'errmsg_ ' . $error};
```

Comment: ${errmsg_ . $error}; will be referred to as a constant, quote them `${'errmsg_'.$error};`

Answer (score 0):

No offence meant but what you're doing is bad design.

A small but no means perfect solution would be store your errors as an Array.

```
$errors = array('Please make changes to your post', 'Please make changes to your post image');
$error = 0;
echo $errors[$error];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this `${$errmsg_.$error}`

This is a variable variable: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to do this:

```
function errorMsg($code)
{
  $msg;
  switch($code)
  {
  case 1:
    $msg = 'Please make changes to your post';
    break;

  case 2:
    $msg = 'Please make changes to your post image';
    break;
  }
  return $msg;
}

echo errorMsg(1);
```

Comment: Why did I get a downvote?  This clearly solves the problem and introduces the OP to functions.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote either, it's a different approach and solves the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$error_msg = 'Please make changes to your ';
$error[1] = 'post';
$error[2] = 'post image';

for($i=1; $i<=count($error); $i++)
 echo $error_msg . $error[$i];
```

Comment: The performance wasted to iterate over an array in order to display the correct answer, against saving a few characters in a string is definitely not worth it.

Comment: If he has to display all the errors, preferably all together at the end of the program, a loop is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays. keep the indexes for easy future reference, as well as easy error message changing and organized API.

```
$errmsg = array(
    1 => 'Please make changes to your post',
    2 => 'Please make changes to your post image'
);

$error = 1;

echo $errmsg[$error]; //'Please make changes to your post';
```